# Find all possible subsets of a short array in C

Tags: c, arrays, opencl, bit-manipulation, subset

I have a relatively short array in C (<32 elements), and want to iterate over all possible subsets of that array of length >= 2. There are many ways of doing so by recursively building a list of all sublists, but I'd like to avoid the extra overhead this adds. All I need is to iterate over each subset; I don't need to keep track of them.

This might sound like a strange requirement, but the reason is that I would also like to be able to use this in an OpenCL kernel where per-work-item memory is quite expensive. Allocating a list of lists is something I'd really like to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include the subsets of size 0 and 1 and just filter them out (which is trivial,
`if ((set & (set - 1)) == 0)`, ignore it), you're really just iterating from 0 to `1 << n`.

That's a lot simpler than Gosper's Hack, which is cool, but since you need essentially all subset lengths anyway there's little point in using it. There are only a couple of subsets that are skipped this way, since the only non-trivial group of them that you don't want only has size `n`.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the array is quite short, we can use some bit-fiddling on a 32-bit unsigned int to accomplish this. If each element of the array is represented as a single bit in the bitstring, and the value of that bit specifies whether that element is in the current subset, then the problem is reduced to one of finding all bitstrings of certain lengths where no bits are set past the `k`th bit position where `k` is the length of the array.

```c
/*
Given:
max = longest subset length
min = shortest subset length
num = number of elements in array
*/

unsigned int i, n, v, w;

// Loop across subset lengths
for (n = max; n >= min; n--) {

    // Generate lexiographically first subset (n rightmost bits set)
    v = (~0U)>>(sizeof(unsigned int)*8-n);

    // Stop once a bit is set that is outside our array
    while (v < (1U<<num)) {
        // Look for elements whose corrensponding bit is set
        for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            if (v & (1U<<i)) {
                // array[i] is in current subset
            }
        }

        // Move to lexiographically next bit string with n bits set
        // http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#NextBitPermutation
        // Could switch to __builtin_ctz() version for speed
        w = (v | (v - 1)) + 1;
        w |= ((((w & -w) / (v & -v)) >> 1) - 1);
        v = w;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an algorithm that can give you the permutation or combiantion sequence given a work-item ID and the array length. Example:

```
Array: 1 2 3
Permutations: 
1 2 3 
1 3 2 
2 1 3
2 3 1
3 1 2
3 2 1

workitem i=5 -> N=3, K=6; *Some algorithm that gives 312*
```

I can guess these algorithms exists, you can even write your own applying logic. (I will try to dig them out later, but search for "parallel permutation/combination")

Then, you only need to write a generic kernel to run the algorithm, with the amount of global size equal to the amount of possible combinations. I would use constant memory for the array values (since it is small in size).
You will also need a BIG output size for all the output values.